# JavaFX WebView not working using a untrusted SSL certificate

Tags: java, ssl, https, javafx, certificate

I'm developing a simple embedded browser using JavaFX:

```
final WebView browser = new WebView();
final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
```

When I use `webEngine` to load any http website, it works fine:

```
webEngine.load("http://google.es");
```

Despite this, if I try to load a website with an untrusted certificate (my own ssl certificate), `webEngine` does not work and I get a white screen in the browser.

Is there any way to (automatically) trust in my ssl certificate?